# How do I get IGTV posts from the Instagram API?

Tags: instagram-api

I pulled the last 10 Instagram posts for a specific user. 2 of those posts are IGTV type posts, but they are not showing up in the list of posts.

It seems the Instagram API is not returning the Instagram TV (IGTV) posts at all.

I have read through the documentation, and can't find how to access Instagram TV posts.

Googled a bunch no one is mentioning this.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation clearly states: “IGTV objects are not supported”

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/

Unfortunately we have to wait for that endpoint